# NativeScript: best persistent cache / storage with view data-binding

Tags: nativescript

I'm developing an app that receives data from API and should store it in some kind of cache to bind it to UI views. This data is also shared among several views and any change to it should be reflected in views. What is the best and fastest option for NativeScript so far? Would be awesome to have something similar to SenchaTouch stores / models with proxy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a singleton and request/import that, just as you would in any other Javascript app. As long as you keep your data in an [Observable](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/data/observable) and any changes to it will instantly be reflected in the views.

E.g.

file: *myData.js*

```
var observableArray = require("data/observable-array");
var observable = require("data/observable");
var DATA = new observable.Observable({
    something: 'a value here',
    somethingElse: 1
    somethingMany: new observableArray.ObservableArray(['a', 'b', 'c'])
});

exports.getData = function() { return DATA; };
exports.fetchFromAPI = function() { /* something that fetches and updates DATA */ }
```

In any file where you want to read that data:

```
var data = require("./myData.js");
console.log(data.getData());
```

Read more about [Observables in NativeScript](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/data/observable)

Comment: That's what I currently do. The problem is I need to synchronize this with any persistent storage all the time. I'm using SQLite plugin for that. But the whole process is pretty sophisticated. I need to check types and convert them. In order to use SQLite plugin I wrote a custom SQL query adapter. I don't really like the implementation. So, I'm looking for a ready-to-go solution like in any other frameworks. I came from Appcelarator and Sencha Touch development where all this is implemented pretty well...

Comment: Afaik there's no out of the box package to do this for you in a NativeScript environment. However, it's not that big of a thing to implement. In your case, you can easily treat the app state (`DATA` in example above) as the master and then just save any changes to a persistent storage by adding an event listener to the propertyChangeEvent event and then save it.

Comment: And again that's what I already do:) I recently moved to weakEvenListeners though, because of my concerns whether NS collects garbage properly. I have 20 different "stores" and many "descendants"from them that bind to views. During the work with the app I see how the memory usage grows rapidly. It even crashed previously, but when I implemented a few optimizations, it stopped to do that. But I'm still not happy with all this mess and would love to see at least a third party solution.

Comment: There is obviously a need for such thing. All other mature framework have this, either as a built-in feature or 3-rd party solution.